# C# Can you assign a set of integers to a specific index or enum?

Tags: c#, arrays, variables, enums

Okay I am trying to practice for an "rpg".

I created an array of monsters that you may encounter, and it will spit out one random monster to fight.

So since im ultra beginner, what do i do now? I am thinking that, for example, if  it spits out zombie, it will have a set of variables/integers attached to it, the health and damage. So, the index [3] will have more information stored with it?

I just learned enums so i was also wondering if something like this would work better over an array or inheritance and polymorphism, since those would work but its much more code to write. I dont even know if C# has the capability to do what i want to do exactly and i need help.

```
string[] monsters = { "goblin", "dog", "ghoul", "zombie" };

Random random = new Random();

int randommonster = random.Next(0, monsters.Length);
```

This was the base to help you picture exactly what i wanted the array or enums to do, then values need to be attached to each monster/index.

Answer (score 1):

C# will be fine for the job.

1. Create a set of classes of type Monster and add the values to the array.
2. Then generate a random index from the array of monsters.
3. Use the values from the Monster object at that index.

   ```
    class Monster
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Health { get; set; }
        public int Damage { get; set; }
        public Monster(string name, int health, int damage)
        {
            Name = name;
            Health = health;
            Damage = damage;
        }
    }
   ```

Then use that class ...

```
Monster[] monsters = 
{
    new Monster("Goblin", 2, 3),
    new Monster("Dog", 3, 4),
    etc ...
}

Random random = new Random();
int monsterIndex = random.Next(0, monsters.Length);

Monster monsterInPlay = monsters[monsterIndex];
```

Comment: thanks so much. If i need to make the damage random, can i do that within the constructor?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.